# Tag property in Swing JTextField

Tags: java, netbeans

I am looking for a way to save a data in the tag `JTextField`. This works well in C# and Delphi in a `textbox`, but if seems that Java does not have this option.

What I need to save is an ID number. How can I do this ?

Comment: What is to save data? What ID number? Where does it appear? Explain your question better please.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extends `TextField`,

then declare the String `tag` and methods to read/write `tag` in the class

For example,

```
static class TextBox extends javax.swing.JTextField
{
    String tag;

    TextBox()
    {
        /* initialization */
    }

    void WriteTag(String input)
    {
        this.tag = input;
    }

    String Readtag()
    {
        return this.tag;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.WriteTag("write something");
    System.out.println(tb.Readtag());
}
```